# Angular error TS2339 Property does not exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript

Hey guys recently I started learning some Angular.

Currently im getting the following Error:

```
32  this.warning.error.push(entry.name+': '+entry.error);
                 ~~~~~
src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:33:15 - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Warning[]'.

33  this.warning.id.push(entry.id);
                 ~~
src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:37:13 - error TS2339: Property 'error' does not exist on type 'Error[]'.

37  this.error.error.push(entry.name+': '+entry.error);
               ~~~~~
src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:38:13 - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Error[]'.

38  this.error.id.push(entry.id);
               ~~
```

Problem is that I defined Interfaces for both that are importet.

```
export interface Error {
        id: number;
        error: string;
        }

export interface Warning {
        id: number;
        error: string;
        }
```

As you can see in my component.

```
import { Error, Warning } from '../dashboard';
...
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
 error: Error[];
 warning: Warning[];
...

evaluate(): void{
        for (let entry of this.status){
        if (entry.status === 0){
                this.ok = this.ok + 1;
                }
        if (entry.status === 1 && entry.value < 8){
        this.warnings = this.warnings + 1;
        this.warning.error.push(entry.name+': '+entry.error);
        this.warning.id.push(entry.wt_id);
                }
        if (entry.status === 1 && entry.value >= 8){
        this.critical = this.critical + 1;
        this.error.error.push(entry.wt_name+': '+entry.error);
        this.error.id.push(entry.wt_id);
                }
        }
}
```

I already tried some things i found in older posts but nothing seems to work.

Maybe some of you guys know a fix and can point it out. Maybe it's just something that I missed.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't pushing to the member variables `error` or `warning` but rather the properties within the variables.

1. You either need to change the type definitions to arrays

**Interfaces**

```js
export interface Error {
  id: number[];
  error: string[];
}

export interface Warning {
  id: number[];
  error: string[];
}
```

**Component**

```js
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  error: Error;
  warning: Warning;
 
  ...
}
```

2. Or push to the member variables instead. As @GunnerB. pointed out in the comments, the arrays `error` and `warning` also need to be initialized before trying to push values to it using `push` function.

**Interfaces**

```js
export interface Error {
  id: number;
  error: string;
}

export interface Warning {
  id: number;
  error: string;
}
```

**Component**

```js
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  error: Error[] = [];              // <-- initialize the arrays
  warning: Warning[] = [];
  ...

  evaluate(): void {
    for (let entry of this.status) {
      if (entry.status === 0) {
        this.ok = this.ok + 1;
      }
      if (entry.status === 1 && entry.value < 8) {
        this.warnings = this.warnings + 1;
        this.warning.push({id: entry.wt_id, error: entry.name + ': ' + entry.error });
      }
      if (entry.status === 1 && entry.value >= 8) {
        this.critical = this.critical + 1;
        this.error.push({id: entry.wt_id, error: entry.name + ': ' + entry.error });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. One addition though: the two arrays need to be initialized somewhere (which at least is not shown in OPs code). Adding a `= []` to both is sufficient.

Comment: @GunnarB.: Yes an often overlooked point. I've edited the answer. Thanks.

Comment: nice one @Michael D really good and seems to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please change to:
`this.warning.error = entry.wt_name + ': ' + entry.error;

`error` in `Warning` interface is string not array.

Comment: But i need it to be an Array. So i guess i should change it to `error: Error[] = [];` ? @Raz Ronen

Comment: correct. And have: `export interface Warning {
  id: number[];
  error: string[];
}`

Comment: Ah very good. Nice to know multiple ways. Thanks for your involvement !